# What are the business benefits of purchasing and utlizing resharper?

Tags: visual-studio, resharper

A co-worker and I are interested in getting resharper integrated into our development environments for the obvious technical benefits (refractoring, etc) but we need to justify to management on how it will help the business make money so that they can purchase it for us.

What reasons would be on the top of the list to justify this purchase? is there a blog post or some similar write-up that I can be pointed to to create a better argument?

**EDIT**

The best 'ammunition' that we could have to get management to purchase ReSharper is for us to be able to quantify (in $) the savings that the company will see from the use of this tool.

**EDIT**

I ended up purchasing a personal license for myself. I don't regret it at all and would recommend anyone to do this if they can't get their company to buy it for them.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Because developers are expensive, and hardware and tools are not. If you purchase resharper and save an hour per day in development time, at 25 bucks an hour, you will reclaim your losses in less than two weeks.

There is no significant training time, because Resharper is written well enough that it takes less time to learn how to use each feature than it does to do whatever it is the developer is trying to do. Once.

If nothing else, just do the following with said manager watching:

```
Navigate to a function DoStuff in unopened (large) class SuperDuperUtility by hand/mouse.
Close window.
(With resharper installed:) CTRL+T SDU <ENTER> ALT+\ DS <ENTER>
```

Your manager will likely say: Why doesn't studio do this already?

If they still won't listen, buy a personal license and when your productivity jumps, ask for a raise.

Comment: You have just increased my love for ReSharper.  I had no idea I could do that.

Answer (score 6):

Measurable Increase in developer productivity.

Answer (score 3):

Increased code quality and consistency through Resharper's suggestions and warnings.

Answer (score 3):

We rolled out ReSharper across our dev team, after a few evangalists kept on about it, I'd reckon it saved 10-15 minutes of dev time/person/day - that soon adds up, with 20 C# developers.

Answer (score 2):

It has a 30-day demo, so try it and see.

I never tried ReShapper, but I highly recommned their competitor [Refactor and CodeRush](http://www.devexpress.com/). Just make sure you watch their videos so you know how to use them properly.

Comment: i have tried it enough to know that it will be beneficial, i just need to sell it to management now.